# WinTV PVR not working in Windows 7 (WinTV-PVR USB)

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, windows-media-center, tuner-card

My Hauppauge WinTV-pvr USB does not work on Windows 7

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a driver for Vista?
Until the manufacturer publishes a Windows 7 driver it probably won't work. 
This is the perils of being an early adopter.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Vista driver in Vista compatibility mode.

Right Click setup>properties>compatibility tab

Answer (score 0):

My WinPVR works fine with Windows 7.

One thing I noticed, is that this software usually runs independently of 'Windows Media Center.' The 'Center' probably relates to the driver that came with Windows 7.

What I did, was go in to the Device manager, and check what driver was installed when I connected my TV Box, to my computer. It's location will be under the heading of 'Sound, video and game controllers.'

Windows 7, installs its own driver, which has to be disabled, or uninstalled.

Then, you click the 'update driver' for the device. You then choose the option of locating the driver yourself. If you use the 'recommended' option, Windows 7, will install its own driver.

Then you go to the location where the driver is. If there is a folder called 'driver[s]' on your installation disk, click on that folder, then hit 'enter.'

You might get a warning saying 'This program [software], cannot be authenticated.' You will then be asked to either stop installation, or continue anyway. Pick 'Continue anyway.'

The driver should install.