# Looking for Windows 7 64-bit external tv tuner drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-media-center, tuner-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WinTV PVR not working in Windows 7 (WinTV-PVR USB)](https://superuser.com/questions/26670/wintv-pvr-not-working-in-windows-7-wintv-pvr-usb)

I have a [Hauppauge WinTV-PVR-USB2](http://www.hauppauge.com/site/products/data_pvrusb2.html) (old but great hardware external tv tuner).

I need a driver for it for Windows 7 x64. Vista 64-bit drivers are said to work and 7 32 bits was adding them after a few tries I don't know why it wasn't adding them at first ...

Thanks for your help dear superusers !!!

Comment: @zillion. Please don't ask the same question multiple times. Please re-edit the original with any further information. Closed. Nothing to see here. Move along now.

Answer (score 0):

According to Hauppauge's support page for the [WinTV-PVR-USB2](http://www.hauppauge.com/site/support/support_pvrusb2.html):

> **Note:** The WinTV-PVR-USB2 model 29XXX
>   is only supported under 32-bit
>   versions of Windows.  Model
>   information can be found on the
>   sticker located on the underside of
>   the WinTV-PVR-USB2.

Check the model number of the bottom of your device and see if it is x64-supported or not. If it is, try using the installation executable on the [support page](http://www.hauppauge.com/site/support/support_pvrusb2.html).

Comment: it work on windows vista 64 bits but I cannot find the drivers and one link on hauppauge website don't work and return to the main page ...